# Save Database connection login and password

Tags: sql-server, database, excel

I have an Excel file connect to the SQL database, every time I open the file its ask me login id and password, is there any way I can store the login information.

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using OLEDB connections in your workbook, you can store username and password in the macro:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID='Id Here'; Password=''Password Here; Data Source= 'DB Name here' ;Use Procedure for Prepare=1" _
     , _
    ";Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID="your workstationid";Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when p" _
    , "ossible=False;Initial Catalog=your catalog"), Destination:=Range("where you want data")). _
    QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = 'your string or query'
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = True
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

End With
```